# Checking If the user entered value is a valid website address/name?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, user-input

So I have an input element in HTML, that input element asks the user for his website's address/name.

Now here's the thing I accept the following address/name formats:

- `https://example.com` (.net, .org, etc.)
- `http://example.com` (.net, .org, etc.)
- `www.example.com` (.net, .org, etc.)
- `http://www.example.com` (.net, .org, etc.)
- `https://www.example.com` (.net, .org, etc.)
- `example.com` (.net, .org, etc.)

But If the user types a random string for example, `abc123$` It would give an error "Please enter a valid website address/name".

What I tried so far,

```
const isValidURL = (str) => {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = str;
  return a.host && a.host != window.location.host;
}

let isValid = isValidURL("https://example.com");

if (isValid == true) {
  // pass
} else if ...
```

Now, this code I found on an SO answer checks to see If it is a valid URL, i.e. contains http or https which is **part of what I want**. But after this in an else if statement I would also want to allow URLs that don't contain http or https but contain www. and then in another else if statement I would want to allow URLs that contain neither of those and just example.com (.net, .org, etc.), but THEN an else statement which tells the user "Please enter a valid website address/name".

But the problem is that I have no idea how I will do this, I would appreciate it if someone were to shed some light upon this.

**Note: I do know that checking the URL on the backend is the best thing to do but sadly due to client requirements I need to use this client-side method of the bare-minimum sitename validation.**

Edit: This is not a duplicate of other such questions because I am not just trying to validate the URLs, I am trying to validate all the possible domain name types valid on a web browser. See the examples I presented above, not all of them are valid URLs the ones that aren't should pass too, but If it is not a valid site name entirely like "example" instead of "example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), or http://example.com, etc." then It doesn't pass.

Comment: It sounds like you already know how to validate URLs beginning with a scheme (http/https) and you'd like to know how to also validate the domain name part (example.com). Could you edit your question to be more specific? I suggest you remove all the http/https examples, since you already know how to handle those.

Comment: Anyway, what is “not working” with the code shown? It’s a good start.

Comment: @charlietfl it's fine for user input, user doesn't have to type a protocol, which can be added on server side

Comment: @user2864740 Nothing not working, I would like to know how to make the domain name validation.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes Charlie, I know It isn't, but I don't specifically want to validate URLs please read my question as I am accepting any website domain types a user might enter (`example.com` or `https://example.com` or even `www.example.com` *BUT NOT* `example` it must contain an ending .text like .com, .net, etc. but It cannot be a simple plain text like "example" It must suit all ways that make a valid website address when typing on Chrome).

Comment: @flppv Please read my question carefully, I am not solely trying to check If it is a URL or not I am actually trying to validate all possible website name combinations as I mentioned earlier, example.com, www.example.com, http://www.example.com, etc. should all be considered valid URLs but NOT example.

Comment: Yes this one answers my question, thanks.